# Joomla! custom module field data inside admin panel

Tags: php, joomla, module

I would like to know how is it possible to call PHP file from backend panel. All should be done in the mod_.xml file

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="basic">
       <field
          name="myname"
          type="mycalledfile"
          label="mylabel"
          extension="mod_mymodule"
          description=""
       />
    </fieldset>
 </fields>
```

I found on the internet that `extension` attribute will call `administrator/components/mod_mymodule/models/fields/mycalledfile.php`, but thats wrong and I want to be able to call file from `modules/` as this is a module. My point is to get data from certain file, or from database call. Either way this has to be done somehow with the .xml file, so this is available via backend admin panel of the module.

Comment: Happy Christmas to you too!)) See this article http://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Joomla-Tips/creating-custom-parameters-in-joomla-16.html

Comment: Thank you! Made it working :) Forgot to use `<fields>` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addfieldpath in fieldset.

```
<fieldset name="basic"  addfieldpath="/administrator/components/mod_xml/models/fields">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what Bogran Burim proposed :) Working great.